# Error creating new project and adding project to gitHub : Server Unreachable

Tags: xcode, github

I'm trying to add new project github but I'm getting this error:

```
The server 'https://<user>@github.com/<user>/helloWorld/' is unavailable or may not exist.  
Check the server address, check your network connection, and then try again.
```

I add the repository under preference->accounts and works just fine.

This are te steps I following to add the project to github

1. Create new project
2. add the name to the project
3. switch on "create git repository on" from "my Mac" to "add to new server" and it will popup a window to add the url
4. I add the github url "`https://<user>@github.com/<user>/helloWorld/`"
5. click next and ask for credentials and I type my credentials
   and after that I'm getting the error:

   ```
   The server 'https://<user>@github.com/<user>/helloWorld/' is unavailable 
   or may not exist.  
   Check the server address, check your network connection, and then try again."
   ```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to create that repo on GitHub itself first
(As in [GitHub help page: "Create a repo"](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo))

[image: https://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/bootcamp/bootcamp_2_newrepo.jpg]

Then you can use that GitHub url as an upstream repo url within your *local* repo.